# How to proceed in this Boundary value problem where Eigen values are calculated numerically?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, elliptic-pde, eigenvalues, linear-pde, problem-solving

While solving a boundary value problem (background provided in the **Context** section) I reach the following variable separated two equations ($F(x)$ and $G(y)$)

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda_h F''' - 2 \lambda_h \beta_h F'' + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) F' + \beta_h^2 F &=& 0, \tag 1\\
V \lambda_c G''' - 2 V \lambda_c \beta_c G'' + \left( (\lambda_c \beta_c - 1) V \beta_c + \mu \right) G' + V \beta_c^2 G &=& 0,\tag 2
\end{eqnarray}
with some separation constant $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$.

with boundary conditions as:

**For G**: $G'(0)=0, G(0)=0$ and $\frac{G''(1)}{G'(1)}=\beta_c$

**For F**: $F'(0)=0$ and $\frac{F''(1)}{F'(1)}=\beta_h$

The non-homogeneous condition in $F$ is:      $\beta_h e^{-\beta_c y}G'(y)F(0)=1$

Since the boundary conditions for $(2)$ are all homogeneous, I have calculated the eigenvalues $\mu_i$ for $(2)$ numerically. For some realistic parameters like `βc = 0.921, λc = 1.775*10^-4, V=1`, these eigen values are

`0.834041, 0.845661, 0.864286, 0.888675, 0.916951, 0.94696, 0.977271, 1.0079, 1.03972, 1.07361, 1.11015,...`

Now since these eigenvalues are numeric in nature, I cannot figure out how to move forward with this problem.

I know from standard PDE problems that these eigen values should be utilized to build the $G$ solution and then should be employed in the $F$ non-homogeneous condition to determine the constants. But how am I supposed to even use orthogonality here ? I would really appreciate if someone could give a step-wise way forward for such problems where the EVs are numeric.

---

**Context**

I had the following system of PDEs
$$\frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x}+\beta_h (\theta_h-\theta_w) = 0 \tag A$$

$$\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} + \beta_c (\theta_c-\theta_w) = 0 \tag B$$

$$\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V\frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x} - V\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} = 0 \tag C$$

with the boundary conditions ($\beta_h, \beta_c, V, \lambda_h, \lambda_c$ are constants)

$$\theta_w(0,y)=1, \theta_w(x,0)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(1,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,1)}{\partial y}=0$$

$$\theta_h(0,y)=1, \theta_c(x,0)=0$$
Using the transformation $\theta_{h1}(x,y):=\theta_h (x,y)-1$ (so that $\theta_w(0,y)=0$ which is needed to get an additional homogeneous condition on $F$) where

\begin{eqnarray}
\theta_{h1}(x,y) &=& \beta_h e^{-\beta_h x} \int e^{\beta_h x} (\theta_w(x,y)-1) \, \mathrm{d}x,\\
\theta_c(x,y) &=& \beta_c e^{-\beta_c y} \int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{eqnarray}

which are substituted in $(C)$ to get:

$$\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} +( -\beta_h - V \beta_c )\theta_w +\beta_h^2 e^{-\beta_h x} \int e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w(x,y)  \mathrm{d}x + \beta_c^2 e^{-\beta_c y}\int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w(x,y)\mathrm{d}y = 0 \tag D$$

Using the ansatz $\theta_w(x,y) = e^{-\beta_h x} f(x) e^{-\beta_c y} g(y)$ on $(D)$ we  obtain two linear third-order ODEs ($1,2$) with constant coefficients for $F(x) := \int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $G(y) := \int g(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$ given in the original question